# Login con acceso multiusuario java y sql

Tags: java, sql

Buenos días estoy tratando de hacer un login multiusuario y se que me falta la validación al momento de comparar usuarios y contraseñas pero no se como realizarlo no se si debería validarlo en el controlador o en la clase desde donde estoy haciendo el método, espero puedan ayudarme.....Les dejo mi código

```
public int Loing(Login log) {
    Integer resultado = 0;
    try {
        
        PreparedStatement st = conexion.prepareStatement("select * from Login Where Usuario='"+log.getUsuario()+"'and Contraseña='"+log.getContraseña()+"' and Tipo ='"+log.getTipo()+"'");

        rs = st.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            resultado = 1;
        } else {
            Mensajes.MD("Problemas en usuario ,contraseña y/o tipo" );
            resultado = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
           
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

//Pertenece al controlador

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnIngresar) {

        String usuario = vista.txtUsuario.getText();
        String contraseña = vista.txtContraseña.getText();
        String tipo = vista.cbotp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Login log = new Login(usuario, contraseña, tipo, 0);
        CRUDlogin l = new CRUDlogin();
        l.Loing(log);
        
        if (vista.cbotp.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            
            
            Main.fa = new FrmAdministrador();
            Main.fa.setVisible(true);
            
        }
        if (vista.cbotp.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
            
            Main.ff = new FrmFarmaceuticos();
            Main.ff.setVisible(true);
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La línea en null no es necesario.

```
    if (rs.next()) {
        resultado = 1;
    } else {
        Mensajes.MD("Problemas en usuario ,contraseña y/o tipo" );
        //resultado = null;   Quitar
    }



 if (e.getSource() == vista.btnIngresar) {    
        String usuario = vista.txtUsuario.getText();
        String contraseña = vista.txtContraseña.getText();
        String tipo = vista.cbotp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Login log = new Login(usuario, contraseña, tipo, 0);
        CRUDlogin l = new CRUDlogin();
        
        if(l.Loing(log)>0){
           if (vista.cbotp.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {                                
               Main.fa = new FrmAdministrador();
               Main.fa.setVisible(true);
            
            }
           if (vista.cbotp.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
               Main.ff = new FrmFarmaceuticos();
               Main.ff.setVisible(true); 
            }          
        }else{
          //Retornas el detalle, usuario no válido
        }       
    }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias! Me funciono